# Вставка ссылки в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять что за фигня, не вставляется ссылка в БД:

> `$link = "<a href='http://google.ru'>1</a>"; $post
> = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (user_id, text) VALUES
> ('$userid','$link')");`

В БД запись не заносится, если вместо ссылки написать простой текст, то всё отработает нормально.. в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $post= mysql_query('INSERT INTO message (`user_id`, `text`) VALUES (\''.((int)$userid).'\',\''.mysql_real_escape_string($link).'\')');
```

Comment: Ну да, проблема в кавычках. Запрос плучался такой:
INSERT INTO message (user_id, text) VALUES
('$userid','<a href='http://google.ru'>1</a>')
Что приводило к синтаксической ошибке